# Simple Point-free functions in Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm still learning Ramda and often have trouble converting seemingly simple lamda functions into point-free pure Ramda functions. Here is a simple example:

```
export const consoleTap = arg =>
  R.compose(
    R.tap,
    R.curryN(2, console[arg])
  );

export const errorTap = consoleTap("error");
export const logTap = consoleTap("log");

// example usage
R.map(logTap("Value"))([1, 2]) // Results in printing "Value 1" "Value 2"
```

The functions work fine and I've even written tests for them. I just get the feeling consoleTap could be written point-free, and there's just something I'm not seeing or understanding correctly. Can the function be rewritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't come up with a point-free version that didn't look overly complicated. I think what you have is pretty good already.

The only suggestion I'd make, would be to split things up: separate logging from `tap`. You could reuse your "prefixed" version of logging on its own:

```
const logWith = (method, prefix) => curryN(2, console[method])(prefix);
const log = logWith('log', 'INFO: ');
const error = logWith('error', 'ERR: ');
log(10); // INFO: 10
error(10); // ERR: 10
```

and with `tap`:

```
const logTap = tap(logWith('error', 'ERR: '));
logTap(10);
// ERR: 10
// => 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is due to [`R.tap`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#tap) not being variadic.

```js
// tap is a unary function
const log = R.tap(console.log);

// logs only `1`
log(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

So you cannot do `log('Value is, 1)`, a workaround could be grouping the arguments for tap with `R.unapply` and then applying them back to the logger via `R.apply`

---

A simple solution could be calling `R.tap` after providing the prefix to the logger:

```js
const logger = R.pipe(
  R.prop(R.__, console),
  R.curryN(2),
);

const error = logger('error');
const log = logger('log');

const result = R.map(
  R.tap(log('value is')),
)([1, 2]);

// tap didn't alter any item inside the functor.
console.log('result is', result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---